# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Worklight Console does not show up after installing WL 6.0 server on Liberty profile - Error 500

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-console

IBM Worklight 6.0 is installed on a Liberty Profile 8.5.5 with a mySQL db. While deploying the application and trying to access the Worklight console the below error is encountered on console

> Error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter[authenticationFilter]: Could not find required filter class - com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.class

Comment: Do you mean you are using an external Liberty profile application server, or the one that is bundled within the Developer Edition? Please edit your question with proper steps of what you're doing. There is not enough information.

Answer (score 4):

In your **server.xml** you need to make sure that your worklight-jee-library.jar is in the application classloader.

```
<application id="worklight" name="worklight" location="BMOMobileBanking.war" type="war" context-root="/worklight">
    <classloader delegation="parentLast">
        <commonLibrary>
            <fileset dir="/my/worklight/lib" includes="worklight-jee-library.jar"/>
        </commonLibrary>
    </classloader>
</application>
```

Make sure the "/my/worklight/lib" points to the directory where this JAR is.   I may suggest **${shared.resource.dir}/worklight/lib**  which usually translates to **$WASLP_HOME/usr/shared/resources/worklight/lib**

Answer (score 1):

I just went through the same issue. For me the issue is related to the worklight database not  existing on my server. So check if the database WRKLGHT and WLREPORT are created and they are properly configured in your server.xml.
Look at the Create and Configure the databases link on the help website here
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc%2Fdeploy%2Fc_deploy_wl_project.html

Answer (score 1):

If you've ensured the `worklight-jee-library.jar` is in the application classloader, and you're still having the problem, then you may have an issue with the Liberty server cache.

Try: `server start worklight --clean`

NOTE: replace worklight with your server name