# Worklight server - Error 500: Could not find required filter class - com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.class

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-8, worklight-server

I'm using worklight 6.1 for my mobile app project. My problem is, I got this error message when I try to upload war file into worklight server. I already install worklight server into my websphere.

```
Error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter [authenticationFilter]: Could not find required filter class - com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.class
```

These are steps for uploading war file into worklight server.

1.Build project_name.war file from IBM Worklight Studio v6.1.
[image]

2.Deploy the .war file to IBM Websphere Integrated Solutions Console v8.5.5.0.
[image]

3.Open the WebSphere enterprise application and click install. 
[image]

4.Choose the project.war file from the worklight project directory. 
[image]

5.Click on next button for fast path. 
[image]

6.Click on next button.
[image]

[image]

7.Choose the server 1.
[image]

8.Choose on the target JNDI.
[image]

9.Set the Virtual Host to default_host.
[image]

10.Set the context root.
[image]

11.Click on finish button.
[image]

12.Save directly to master configuration.
[image]

13.Start the application.
[image]

[image]

14.Open the server URL to get into the wroklight server to deploy application, adapter and etc, but failed to open the server URL with this error and the error log as below.
[image]

```
[3/6/14 10:18:50:442 MYT] 0000009e webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor]: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: class java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter
at java.beans.Beans.instantiate(Beans.java:195)
at java.beans.Beans.instantiate(Beans.java:80)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager._loadFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:533)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.loadFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:475)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.getFilterInstanceWrapper(WebAppFilterManager.java:308)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.getFilterChain(WebAppFilterManager.java:380)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:892)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3761)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:976)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:283)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)
```

My latest error message on 10 March 2014

```
Error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException: Worklight Console initialization failed.Logged Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: FWLSE0206E: The project /rmbp failed to initialize, because the project database schema for data source jdbc:db2://192.168.1.80:50001/APPCNTR is from version N/A, which is not supported by the server from version 6.1.0.00.20131126-0630. Use the Worklight ant tasks to upgrade the project database schema.
```

Comment: Make sure you've followed these manual steps to the letter: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/admin/t_configuring_websphere_application_server_manually.html - also, you could have just used the ant task scripts...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to look at this similar post for suggestions:

[IBM Worklight 6.0 - Worklight Console does not show up after installing WL 6.0 server on Liberty profile - Error 500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886222/ibm-worklight-6-0-worklight-console-does-not-show-up-after-installing-wl-6-0-s)

Importantly "you need to make sure that your worklight-jee-library.jar is in the application classloader." Like Idan suggested above you can easily use the ant scripts we provide in order to accomplish this in a more automated fashion:

https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc%2Fdevref%2Ft_transporting_apps_and_adapters.html